# Can I create a capsule that provides COVID-19 information to Bixby users?

Tags: bixby

I'd like to make a capsule that provides COVID-19 information to Bixby users. Can I do that? If so, what steps should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer is available here: https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046511534-Can-I-create-a-capsule-that-provides-COVID-19-information-to-Bixby-users- and will be updated with newer information as it becomes available

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a capsule that provides Covid-19 information.
You just need to find an endpoint (any JSON is fine, you can easily find it on GitHub) and change it to your needs.

A good example on the "how to" is this video, very straightforward:

[How to create a capsule](https://youtu.be/K9bEO9Y9w48)

Hope this can help.

Cheers.